# s3 simultaneous download and upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having a service that uploads files during the day. The same file gets updated multiple time on different events (no determined way to know when it gets updated). At the same time there is a client that downloads the file. What happens if the file gets updated during the download? Does s3 still preserve an old version until all active processes with it are done (kind of like filesystem)? Can the file be corrupted (part from old version, part from new)? Can the connection be closed abruptly in this case?

Answer (score 3):

An object will only be created in Amazon S3 if the upload process completed fully. Partial files will *not* appear in Amazon S3.

Similarly, when **overwriting** an object in Amazon S3, the object will only be replaced if the new object was fully uploaded. The new object *completely* replaces the old object.

There might be a small delay between the upload completing and the new object appearing because objects in Amazon S3 are replicated between multiple servers for durability.

Comment: Thank you John. What about the file that is process of being downloaded when a new object has been created? Will the download be aborted, will the file be object partially from old version, partially from new version, or will it succeed consistently?

Comment: I have no idea! It would be quite difficult to try and create such a situation for testing purposes too.